# how to send data to controller using method post inside looping data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, codeigniter

i want to post the data to detail controller using form method, and the it needs some of the data from the previous view.

this is my view:

```
    <form role="form" action="<?php echo URL_CTR;?>general/do_performance/detail" method="post">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="per_provinsi">
            <h3 style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;" class="text-center" id="title_do_1">Performance by <?php echo lang('gen.province.text');?></h3>
            <table class="table mb0 table-striped" id="table_1" class="table_width">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 1%;"><?php echo lang('gen.no.text');?></th>
                        <th>Plant</th>
                        <th><?php echo lang('gen.province.text');?></th>
                        <th style="width: 10%;">Total DO</th>
                        <th style="width: 10%;">DO tidak terlambat</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%;">Lead Time Performance</th>
                        <th style="width: 5%;"><?php echo lang('gen.option.text');?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="data_1">
                </tbody>
            </table><br>
        </div>
    </form
```

and this is my script:

```
    function load_data_1(data) {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var a = '<tr>\
                    <th>' + (i + 1) + '</th>\
                    <td>' + data[i].gudang_nama + '<br>( ' + data[i].gudang_no_referensi + ')</td>\
                    <td>' + data[i].provinsi_nama + '<br>( ' + data[i].provinsi_id + ')</td>\
                    <td>' + data[i].total_data + '</td>\
                    <td>' + data[i].tepat_waktu + '</td>\
                    <td>' + data[i].delivery_rate + '</td>\

                    //this is the data i wanted to send
                    <input type="hidden" name="plant_id" value="'+data[i].gudang_id+'">\
                    <input type="hidden" name="param_id" value="'+data[i].provinsi_id+'">\
                    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="1">\

                    <td>\
                        <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle btn-xs" type="submit" title="<?php echo lang('gen.detail.text');?>"><?php echo lang('gen.detail.text');?></button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>';
            html = html + a;
        }
        $("#table_1").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#data_1').html(html);
        $('#table_1').dataTable({
            // "scrollX": true,
        });
    }
```

i want to pass the data to this controller:

```
public function detail() {
    $data = array();

    $data["plant_id"]= $this->input->post('plant_id');
    $data["code"]= $this->input->post('code');
    $data["param_id"]= $this->input->post('param_id');

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

but the result shows the last of the for data (plant_id 104 and param_id 891 are the last data of the looping):

```
{
    plant_id: "104", //this is the last data in looping for
    code: "1",
    param_id: "891", //this is the last data in looping for
}
```

in looping 'for', How to send only the data when the same row of the button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of various fields to use array, so `plant_id` should be `plant_id[]`.

Below is how the updated code will look like.

```
                    <input type="hidden" name="plant_id[]" value="'+data[i].gudang_id+'">\
                    <input type="hidden" name="param_id[]" value="'+data[i].provinsi_id+'">\
                    <input type="hidden" name="code[]" value="1">\
```

You can read the value in the Controller as you are doing currently. It will now be an `array` instead of `string`.